# Dateformat change from PST to GMT

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

Trying to convert variable preDate (PST) to GMT format without success, iv'e tried two different approaches.

preDate = "1/25/2016" (current value)

postDate = "25-1-2016" **or** "25/1/2016" (value i wish to have)

**Function A)**

```
function myFunction1() {
      var preDate = "1/25/2016";

      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(preDate, "GMT", "d-MM-yyyy");
      Logger.log(formattedDate);
      }
```

> Cannot find method formatDate(string,string,string)

**Function B)**

```
function myFunction2(){
  var preDate = "1/25/2016";
  if (typeof preDate === "date"){
 var nydate = Utilities.formatDate(preDate, "GMT", "d-MM-yyyy"); 
  }
  Logger.log(nydate);
}
```

> [16-11-24 14:15:16:532 CET] undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatDate method requires the first parameter as Date and not String. Here's a modified version that should work. Make sure the default timezone of your Google Script is set as PST.

```
function myFunction1() {
  var preDate = new Date("1/25/2016");
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(preDate, "GMT", "d-MM-yyyy");
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
}
```

Comment: That gives me the correct format, but wrong day, what i see in the logger:  "24-01-2016" why did it cut away one day? Thank you for being patience with me Amit, appreciated!

Comment: Don'tuse hard coded time zone values, you'll have to change them twice every year... Use session.getScriptTimeZone() instead, it will always be right automatically.